# Help with update list item

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, item, update

I built an approval workflow on a sp 2013 list A. Now I create another workflow on the task list of this workflow to do one thing:

whenever an item on list A get approved, I want the workflow update a column (WF) on List A to "`Approved`".

This is the workflow I did on the task list.

```
if current item: Task Outcome equals Approved
update item in List A.
```

Now, how can find the current item that I can update the WF COLUMN TO "`Approved`"?
I tried to use `task id= item id` , but that's not right...Can anyone help?

Henry

Answer (score 0):

In task list the item id is stored in `Workflow List Id` field. You can use that for finding the Parent Item.

Also I would suggest you change your approach and use a Workflow associated with `List A`. In that workflow you can use Stages and Parallel Actions to achieve the same.

Check this question to get an idea on how to implement this - [Workflow wait for task complete OR date/time](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105828/workflow-wait-for-task-complete-or-date-time)